# Correct resolution of vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

There's a sum given as an example in my physics textbook which I tried to solve in a different manner but ended up with a wrong answer. Here's a picture of the sum given in my textbook along with the solution that they provided.
[image: (Example 7.7 in the image)]

And here is what I tried to do.
I resolved the vectors as shown in this picture [image: this]

After that, I equated: N = mg cos α, which contradicts equation (ii) in my book.

Then, I proceeded as per my book,
N sin α = mRω² ---- Equation (i)

Substituting the previous value of N (= mg cos α ) in Equation (i), I got a different value of " ω " from that given in the answer.

What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: In general, people here won't work out problems for you. See 
http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391 for a list of 
sites that might.

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind.